# How to get and save a calculated address in x86_64 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I have a little experience in assembler.
Suppose I have code like this, for example:

```
destAddr:
DD 00
MOV [r12+rcx*8+20],r10
```

What I need to do is get the value of (r12+rcx*8+20) stored in a variable in the memory(destAddr).

```
// r12+rcx*8+20 = 0x707B8C030 --> example
MOV destAddr, r12+rcx*8+20 ---> how to do it?
```

At the end I need to have 0x707B8C030 as a value in destAddr.
Thank You in advance.

Comment: `lea rax, [r12+rcx*8+20]; mov [destAddr], rax`. Note that  `DD` is dword while you need qword `DQ` because addresses are 8 bytes.

Comment: Welcome - Please check out how to ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Proof read before posting. Two typo bugs crept into your title...